# Oracle PL/SQL MERGE but skip Locked Rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm running a PL/SQL Script that works primarily on file F41021 (one of the heaviest) & I want to find a way to ignore any lock by application or other session that could slow down the run, because the number of items to be UPDATEd is very high & there needs to be logic behind the update.

I'm using a simple MERGE structure.
Here a pseudo-code:

```
DECLARE
{Variables};
BEGIN
    FOR T IN ({Subquery}) LOOP

        INSERT INTO Table_Temp
        SELECT {Extensive calculation} FROM {Many Tables};

        MERGE INTO Table_1
        USING (SELECT * FROM Table_Temp WHERE {Conditions for Table_Temp})
        ON ({Pivoting Fields})
        WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
        SET {Updatable Fields};

    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

The problem I'm foreseeing is that, if there is a lock in any of the rows, the SQL will wait for that lock to be COMMITted: locks caused by stuck processes will be a nightmare. Provided the high number of items, I cannot afford to wait or be monitoring locked sessions.

I don't see how I can add a FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED. As well, I'm looking for something that on its own won't heavily impact the performance (for instance, UPDATE from subquery is too slow). I can neither afford to have the PL/SQL interrupted due to a bad record: we need to UPDATE what can be UPDATEd & later deal with the remaining items, which means breaking the SQL with an EXCEPTION or error won't help, because that will force us to restart the run.

Is there a way to have the MERGE statement detect any lock & ignore it instead of waiting for it to be released? Probably an SQL-hint?

Comment: Have you tried :
MERGE INTO (SELECT * FROM Table_1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED) ... ?

Comment: Hi @p3consulting, if I use that approach, I would need to create a subquery to filter the rows. I think that would be going back to the slow rate I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @p3consulting, just for the record, it didn't allow me to add the "FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED". Error was "Missing Right Parenthesis" after the Table_1.

Comment: Indeed "FOR UPDATE  ... " is not accepted in subselect: what works - from the syntax problematic aspect, but still to investigate for performance and functionality - is to create a PIPELINED function using a CURSOR with the "FOR UPATE..." and used that function in the MERGE: SELECT * FROM TABLE(pipelined_function), this requires creating an OBJECT of same definition as the ROWTYPE of your table and a TABLE OF that new object type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first select from Table_1 where {that_where_condition_for_update} for update nowait and handle the exception that is raised when a locked row is encountered. And only if no locked rows are found run the merge statement. Still, there is something about the merge statement, that causes it to lock not only the rows that are affected by the update (or delete, as the case might be). For which cause I'd say it would be better if you could avoid the merge altogether and have an update and an insert.

Comment: I did try using UPDATE, but the UPDATE is taking too long in spite of the usage of indexed columns. The table in general has become gargantuan & my update is a lengthy one (300K in a single site). I did notice that MERGE did the work at an acceptable rate.

Comment: If there are very many rows to update, maybe you could use the facilities of dbms_parallel_execute to split the rows in chunks and have a transaction for the update of each chunk.